# "find -type f -iname '*.txt' | xargs -I {} echo ""> {}" does not work

Tags: linux, bash

I am working on linux bash. Now I would like to clear the contents of all *.txt files. However, this command "find -type f  -iname '*.txt' | xargs -I {} echo ""> {}" seems not to work. Any suggestions? Any ideas about better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced `echo` with `truncate` in order to clear a file and used find's `-exec` instead of piping to `xargs`:

`find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec truncate -s 0 {} \;`